# How to use onsubmit with asp.net masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have a asp.net masterpage. And there i have a form

```
<form id="frmStuff" runat="server" onsubmit="ContentLoader();">
```

And like you see, i try to call a javascript function with onsubmit.

But this doesn't work. It does nothing.

I think this has something to do with the Masterpage.

Is there any way to use unsubmit?

Thank you for reading.
Daniel

Edit:

```
  <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="onlineHypBO.master.vb" Inherits="onlineHypBO.onlineHypBO" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="css/bo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Skins/50pxMetro/ComboBox.50pxMetro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ohbo.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmOnlineHypBO" runat="server" onsubmit="ContentLoader();">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                    Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
                </asp:ScriptReference>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                    Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
                </asp:ScriptReference>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" 
                    Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
                </asp:ScriptReference>
            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="navPos">
        <div id="navAlpha">
           ...
        </div>
        <div id="navAlpha2">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navBeta">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHelp" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphFooter" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <div class="btnZurueckFooter"><telerik:RadButton ID="rbZurück" runat="server" Text="Zurück" Width="150px" Skin="Office2010Blue"></telerik:RadButton></div>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>                    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

    <script src="js/unslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            .....
        </script>
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have <input type="submit"/> in your form?

Comment: What kind of Code you wanna see? I Edit the MasterPage to my Post.

Comment: I found a solution maybe. I can open my function with this: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "script", "ContentLoader();", True)